# In Final Fantasy VII is there any way to save Aeris?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In Final Fantasy VII is there any way to save Aeris?

I heard once you could bring her back to life.

Comment: @Davide Spoiler in title, please reformulate the question to avoid reveal Aeris story

Comment: I know this is going to quickly become the most downvoted answer on Gaming, but I can't resist: [Yes, there is a way.](http://xkcd.com/299/)

Comment: @marco I hope that is sarcastic. The only thing that is even more common knowledge among gamers is the cake being a lie. Besides, a spoiler for a game which is from 1997?

Comment: Spoilers should be kept sacred. 
http://xkcd.com/606/
I'm that guy, but farther behind.

Comment: @macha I am not sarcastic, spoiler rules should be general and not released-year dependent

Comment: I have to say it, almost everyone of us didn't care about her in the least and it was almost punishment to have her in your party until she died THEN I cared

Comment: But... but... "Aeris" is an anagram for "Raise"!!! There must be a way! :P

Comment: Sure, spoilers should be kept sacred, but What's the statute of limitations? http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2005/12/05/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a dumb rumor.

Comment: Have you tried using Phoenix Wing ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No. You can cheat with things like the game genie, but she cannot be "legally" brought back.

Answer (score 25):

It is possible to prevent her death; don't progress in the main storyline far enough to cause her to die. This will prevent you from completing the main story, but you will have saved her life! Is finishing the game really worth Aeris' life?

Comment: Technically Nick is right !

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who thought of this answer when reading the question.

Comment: As the saying goes, "the only way to win is to not play." ;)

Comment: I have never considered it like this!  I guess I'll never, ever finish disc 1 ever again!

Answer (score 16):

No, but you can see her again. On disc three, revisit the church in Midgar in the Sector 5 slums. A silhouette of Aeris (or her "ghost" as some fans will say) will appear near the flower patch for a brief moment.

Aside from that, only cheats (gameshark, etc.) can get her back to your party.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Nope. (makes it more impactful!)

There was a rumor I read that there was going to be a way to resurrect Aris, but due to time restraints for the Japan launch this was taken out. And apparently there are a few dead end dialogues and mini side quests around that don't lead to anything but where for the purpose of this.

The USA version has an extra FMV and other bits added in that they didn't have time for in the Japanese version, however it's all minor and if the rumor of time was the reason she couldn't be brought back to life then this is a good thing as it add's a great level of emotion to the game.

- Each FF game someone major normally dies.. sob.

Comment: i don't remember anyone major dying in ff8...

Comment: @spartacus The FF series itself is what died in FF8.

Comment: @Fambida: Meh.  All FF8 did was take all of the things FF7 got wrong and double down on them.  Neither game has got a thing on the SNES Final Fantasy titles, either story-wise or gameplay-wise.

Comment: @Fambida you sure spell "10" a weird way...