# Can I get this character back after Disc 1 of Final Fantasy VII?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Final Fantasy VII is there any way to save Aeris?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/904/in-final-fantasy-vii-is-there-any-way-to-save-aeris)

I just finished Disc 1 of Final Fantasy VII where Sephiroth killed Aeris. Is Aeris permanently out of your party? The reason I ask is that I found Aeris has a level 4 limit break called Great Gospel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For starters, I'm incredibly surprised you've managed to avoid knowing the answer to this question since 1997 when the game was released! Well done, in a way :)

I'd recommend just playing the game and finding out the answer to your question, as it's more meaningful to find out through the game than just reading it online. But in case you're really desperate...

> Yes, she is totally, utterly dead. Like most deaths, it is irreversible (zombies excluded).

Comment: rofl thanks . Google is not my friend. Im afraid I'll spoil the entire game if I read up an entire walkthrough

Comment: IIRC, Great Gospel makes the entire party invincible. It would be fairly game-breaking to have all the time at the end of the game. :3

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no way to get her back without editing the save file or using some form of cheat device (game shark, pc game trainer, ect.).

Comment: against cheating XD and against walkthroughs too :? I usually ask 1 answer questions

Comment: Funnily enough, if you use gameshark to get Aerith after she is dead, she have ACTUAL dialogue in various place.